# How can I achieve Windows-like drag and drop behaviour?

Tags: drag-and-drop

It is a problem to drag item from one window to another when they are overlapped. When we click in a window it immediately focused and upper window go behind of this. But I found that in Windows and Mac they immediately focused when press in blank space, When select an item it does not switch immediately. It switched after release mouse button.

So main idea like this:

1. When click on blank space (lower window) then switch focus after press mouse button (not release)
2. When click on an item (select something) then switch focus after release mouse button (hold switch focus until mouse button release)

I want to simulate this in Ubuntu. So need to replace mouse press and release behaviour. Means when mouse press it signal to Ubuntu that it release and vice versa. How to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,